Cant achieve smoothness on opening div in jquery, css
So I am writing a slide-down animation for my calculator, I have read all sources on the web, but still cant seem to achieve the smoothness on the div. Some content slides out, but half of it and the background container seems to just pop up.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.calculator-container').hover(function() {
    $('.calculator-container').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
html {
  font-family: Lora;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

b {
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  margin: 10px 0px 4px 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 100px;
}

.calculator-container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 40px 45px 40px 45px;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.calculator-content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.calculator-container.open .calculator-content {
  height: 100%;
  /* Adjust the height accordingly */
}

.select_container {
  font-family: Lora;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 7.025px;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.select_span_container {
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  color: #495057;
  border-left: none;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.select_span_container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.select_container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.input_box {
  font-family: Lora;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px;
  flex: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.input_box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.input_span_box {
  font-family: Lora;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  color: #495057;
  border-left: none;
}

.input_container {
  display: flex;
}

.input_container input {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.checkbox_container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.calculator_solvebutton {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.calculator_solvebutton:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="calculator-container">
  <b style="font-size:34px; padding-bottom: 20px;">Algas kalkulators</b>

  <div class="calculator-content">
    <label for="year">Izvēlieties aprēķina gadu:</label>
    <select class="select_container" id="year" name="year">
      <option value="g24">2024. gads</option>
      <option value="g23">2023. gads</option>
    </select>

    <label for="salary">Mēnēšalga: </label>
    <div class="input_container">
      <input class="input_box" type="number" min="1" max="500000" step="0.01" id="salary">
      <span class="input_span_box">EUR/mēnesis</span>
    </div>

    <label for="dependant">Apgādājamo personu skaits: </label>
    <input class="input_box" type="number" min="0" max="20" step="1" id="dependant">

    <label for="minimum">Mēneša neapliekamais minimums: </label>
    <div class="input_container">
      <input class="input_box" type="number" min="0" max="500" step="0.01" id="minimum">
      <span class="input_span_box">EUR/mēnesis</span>
    </div>

    <b style="font-size:26px; margin-top: 10px"> Papildu noteikumi </b>

    <label for="disability">Invaliditāte: </label>
    <select class="select_container" id="disability">
      <option value="no">Nav</option>
      <option value="g1-2">1. vai 2. grupa</option>
      <option value="g3">3. grupa</option>
    </select>

    <div class="checkbox_container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="NPK">
      <label for="NPK">Politiski represēta vai NPK persona</label>
    </div>

    <button class="calculator_solvebutton" onclick="calculateSalary()">Aprēķināt</button>

  </div>
</div>



How can I achieve perfect smoothness, should jquery be used in this case?

you should slide down to a specific height (i.e 400px) and not 100%

When you transition the height of an element, you cause its content to reflow many times during the transition. That’s a lot of work to do every fraction of a second. I’m sure it would be smoother to transition the position (top) instead of the height.


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.calculator-container').hover(function() {
    $('.calculator-container').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
html {
  font-family: Lora;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

b {
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  margin: 10px 0px 4px 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 100px;
}

.calculator-container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 0 45px 40px 45px;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  transition: height 1s;
}

.calculator-content {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: top 1s;
  top: -380px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.calculator-container.open {
  height: 480px;
}

.calculator-container.open .calculator-content {
  top: 60px;
  /* Adjust the height accordingly */
}

.select_container {
  font-family: Lora;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 7.025px;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.select_span_container {
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  color: #495057;
  border-left: none;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.select_span_container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.select_container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.input_box {
  font-family: Lora;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 6px;
  flex: 1;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.input_box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.input_span_box {
  font-family: Lora;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  color: #495057;
  border-left: none;
}

.input_container {
  display: flex;
}

.input_container input {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.checkbox_container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.calculator_solvebutton {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

.calculator_solvebutton:hover {
  background-color: #0056b3;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="calculator-container">
  <p style="margin-top: 0; font-size: 34px; padding: 22px 0; background: #f4f4f4; position: relative; z-index: 10; font-weight: bold;">Algas kalkulators</p>

  <div class="calculator-content">
    <label for="year">Izvēlieties aprēķina gadu:</label>
    <select class="select_container" id="year" name="year">
      <option value="g24">2024. gads</option>
      <option value="g23">2023. gads</option>
    </select>

    <label for="salary">Mēnēšalga: </label>
    <div class="input_container">
      <input class="input_box" type="number" min="1" max="500000" step="0.01" id="salary">
      <span class="input_span_box">EUR/mēnesis</span>
    </div>

    <label for="dependant">Apgādājamo personu skaits: </label>
    <input class="input_box" type="number" min="0" max="20" step="1" id="dependant">

    <label for="minimum">Mēneša neapliekamais minimums: </label>
    <div class="input_container">
      <input class="input_box" type="number" min="0" max="500" step="0.01" id="minimum">
      <span class="input_span_box">EUR/mēnesis</span>
    </div>

    <b style="font-size:26px; margin-top: 10px"> Papildu noteikumi </b>

    <label for="disability">Invaliditāte: </label>
    <select class="select_container" id="disability">
      <option value="no">Nav</option>
      <option value="g1-2">1. vai 2. grupa</option>
      <option value="g3">3. grupa</option>
    </select>

    <div class="checkbox_container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="NPK">
      <label for="NPK">Politiski represēta vai NPK persona</label>
    </div>

    <button class="calculator_solvebutton" onclick="calculateSalary()">Aprēķināt</button>

  </div>
</div>



